# How to post image in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

Actually am new to Angular2. In post method I don't know how to upload image in angular2 .
Other fields also there like(product name, type, category ..etc) along with that i want to post the image.
Below i have mentioned my Html,conponent.ts and service.ts. 
 so please tell me how to do that?

**HTML**

```
          <div class="form-group image">
            <input type="file" (change)="onfileSelected($event)" class="form-control" multiple="">
            <span style="padding-left:22%">
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </a>&nbsp; | &nbsp;
              <a href="#">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </a>
            </span>
          </div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
 onfileSelected(event) {
    console.log(event);
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
  }



 createNewProduct(productForm: NgForm) {

    this.productService.save_user(productForm.value)
      .subscribe(response => {
        const toast_parameter = this.notificationService.getToast('success', 'New Product', 'Inserted Successfully');
        this.toastConfig = toast_parameter.config;

        this.toasterService.popAsync(toast_parameter.toast);
      },
        error => {
          const toast_parameter = this.notificationService.getToast('error', 'New Product', 'Error Occurred!!');
          this.toastConfig = toast_parameter.config;
          this.toasterService.popAsync(toast_parameter.toast);
        });

  }
```

**Service.ts**

```
  save_user(product_data: any): Observable<any[]> {

        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }),
        };
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/product/', product_data, httpOptions)
            .map(response => response)
            .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.statusText));
    };
```

**model.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='myphoto/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, max_length=255)
    pro_name =  models.CharField(max_length=25)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sales = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    cost = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    taxable = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    tax_details= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    type_units = models.ForeignKey(Units, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hsn = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):    
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=False, max_length=None, allow_empty_file=True,  use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id','image','pro_name','description','category','sales','cost','taxable','tax_details','type_units','hsn')
```

Comment: where is your `onfileSelected` method in the component?

Comment: sorry i have forgot to upload that . now u can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send image/file you need to send data in the form of `FormData` so add your whole data in formData and send it back to your server

```
<input type="file" (change)="onfileSelected($event.target.files)" class="form-control" multiple="">



onfileSelected(event) {
 console.log(event);
 this.form.image = <File>event.target.files[0];
}

createNewProduct() {
  this.productService.save_user(this.setFormData(this.form.value))
    .subscribe(response => {
      const toast_parameter = this.notificationService.getToast('success', 'New Product', 'Inserted Successfully');
      this.toastConfig = toast_parameter.config;

      this.toasterService.popAsync(toast_parameter.toast);
    },
      error => {
        const toast_parameter = this.notificationService.getToast('error', 'New Product', 'Error Occurred!!');
        this.toastConfig = toast_parameter.config;
        this.toasterService.popAsync(toast_parameter.toast);
      });

}

setFormData(param) {
  let formData = new FormData();
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(param).length; i++) {
    let key = Object.keys(param)[i];
    let data = param[key];
    formData.append(key, data);
  }
  return formData;
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me that what i want to mention in Component.ts.

Comment: @SudharsanVenkatraj Please check updated answer. You have to set your whole data into the formData format and replace your `formname` with yours, if you need help let me know.

Comment: you have mentioned formname in that what i want to replace. Actually i was new to this technology so please tell me what i want to mention there.

Comment: Replace your Form Model name with the keyword `formname` i mentioned

Comment: I strongly recommend to learn angular forms first and basic concept :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you change service inseted using http call change into **XMLHttpRequest**

```
file:File;
onfileSelected(event: EventTarget) {
    let eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext> event;
    let target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement> eventObj.target;
    let files: FileList = target.files;
    if(files) {
        this.file: File = files[0];
      }
}
public save_user(filedata: File) {
    let url = 'your url'
    if (typeof filedata != 'undefined') {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let formData: any = new FormData();
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            formData.append('image', filedata, filedata.name);
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.send(formData);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
this.service.saveUser(this.file)
                .then(data=>{
                    console.lo(' image File uploaded')
                })
```

in your backend you can get from **request.FILES**

```
image = request.FILES['image']
```

Comment: In observable patten how to do that.